# Eclipse,Android studio, Intellij . Error al ejecutar importacion de lidgdx. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Tags: android-studio, eclipse, libgdx

No puedo ejecutar correctamente mi aplicacion importada de lidgdx, el ejemplo inicial. Al ejecutar
en cualquier ide, Eclipse, Android Studio o Intellij. Aparece solo el marco de la ventana y transparente.
Adjunto imagen:
[image: Error que me ocurre en Eclipse, y me ocurre igual en los otros ides.]

Creo que puede ser por que mi equipo es muy modesto. Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo tiempo con esto, y me encantaria una aclaracion. Seguramente no tiene arreglo, y lo unico sera cambiarme de equipo. Me gustaria una respuesta y salir de este bache . Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para cualquier persona que tenga este problema. Ayer di con la solucion. Tuve que actualizar la tarjeta de video y arreglado. Asi que con un Intel core duo , 3gb de  ram y 512mb de tarjeta de video estoy corriendo el android studio importando proyectos de libgdx, estupendo......